# How to create a specific COM Object class?

Tags: python, com, win32com, com-automation

I have a COM object, that have a lot of classes. So, I create a new object:

```
PSSForeCourt = win32com.client.Dispatch("PSS.ForeCourt")
```

It is a `ForeCourt` class. This object has a function `GetPrices(param1, param2)`.

- `param1` - This is integer,
- `param2` - This is empty variable of `PriceGroup` class type.

So, how can I create a new variable with specific class (`PriceGroup`)? `ForeCourt` class is a parent of the `PriceGroup` class.

Comment: It typically depends on the "object model" you're working with. It should be documented by the PSS.ForeCourt developer

Comment: Could be that PriceGroup is an typed enum (ie really just an integer). As @SimonMourier says, check the documentation. Another way is to use `win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch` and inspect the generated python files for the type you are interested in.